# library of ready-made regular expression templates to check the most popular data formats

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Is there a list / library of ready-made regular expression templates to check the most popular data formats like email and phone, etc. for Python3?

Comment: There is [so]. More than likely there is a question that has already been answered for whatever common regex you're looking for.

Comment: @Sayse,  it’s not convenient to search every time, I want to have a convenient library right in python

Answer (score 1):

You can try [regexlib](http://regexlib.com/), they have a lot of standard regular expressions for the most common use cases.

Comment: For example I need to check that the proxy is entered correctly, in the format user:password@ip:port, I can't find it here, I'm not looking for it or is it not there?